# How to refer to external SubRepo in the .hgsub file?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I want to add a SubRepo which is outside the folder of the MainRepo
as this SubRepo will be the SubRepo of many Big Main Repos at the same time for a certain design purpose.
Example:
Main is a big Repo
Main2 is a big Repo
my_lib is a subRepo for both Main and Main2 Repos

Main `.hgsub`:

```
../../my_lib = server_path
```

Main2 `.hgsub`:

```
../../my_lib = server_path
```

But mercurial doesn't allow relative paths to be outside of the Big Repo.

Is there any possible way to add the SubRepos outside the Main Repo ?